# Passing data for EFlot chart

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to generate a simple line chart of data of temperatures. The table in the database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      locationId INTEGER,
      value REAL NOT NULL,
      createDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY(locationId) REFERENCES location(id));
```

and the columns, I'm interested are: `createDate` and `value`.

I've trying to use [EFlot](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/flot/), which expects to have data in form of array of arrays, like this as an example:

```
            'data'=>array(
                array(1,1),
                array(2,7),
                array(3,12),
                array(4,32),
                array(5,62),
                array(6,89),
            ),
```

When I use static array like that, my browser shows script data like this:

```
... [{'label':'line','data':[[1,1],[2,7],[3,12],[4,32],[5,62],[6,89]], ...
```

and the graph naturally works ok.

However, I am not able to formulate the data dynamically from the model. I have tried for example following:

```
$arr = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT id, value FROM temperature')->queryAll();
....
'data'=>$arr,
```

which evaluates as:

```
... $.plot($('#yw2'), [{'label':'line','data':[{'id':'949','value':'20.812'},{'id':'950','value':'20.875'},{'id':'951','value':'21.125'},{'id':'952','value':'21.25'},{'id':'953','value':'21.312'},{'id':'954','value':'21.375'}], ....
```

and the graph does not work.

I suppose, the final goal would be to have a function for model, so I could use it like this:

```
...
'data'=>$model->getGraphData(),
....
```

But, how to construct such a function? 
What should it return to get this graph working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it sorted out.

1. In the model, I added the following function:

   ```
   public function getGraphData()
   {
           $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
       $criteria->addCondition('createDate > datetime(\'now\', \'-1 day\', \'localtime\')');

           $sort = new CSort();
           $sort->defaultOrder='createDate';

           return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                   'criteria'=>$criteria,
                   'sort'=>$sort,
                   'pagination'=>false,
           ));
   }
   ```
2. And the in the view

   ```
   foreach($model->getGraphData()->getData() as $row) {
                   $data[]=array($row['id'],$row['value']);
           };

   $this->widget('application.extensions.EFlot.EFlotGraphWidget',
       array(
           'data'=>array(
               array(
                   'label'=> 'line',
                   'data'=>$data,
                   'lines'=>array('show'=>true),
                   'points'=>array('show'=>true),
               ),
           ),
           'options'=>array(
                   'legend'=>array(
                       'position'=>'nw',
                       'show'=>true,
                       'margin'=>10,
                       'backgroundOpacity'=> 0.5
                       ),
           ),
           'htmlOptions'=>array(
                  'style'=>'width:800px;height:400px;'
           )
       )
   );
   ```

And it works :-)